# lookup type on "this" of a typescript class

Tags: typescript

I want to use the type of a property of a class inside it. I found lookup type which matches the use case.

This code is to be used at many setters in different classes. So I want to reduce adjustment after copy and pasting the code.

It the missing support for direct "this" a bug / missing feature or is there a reason not to support the pattern?

```
class myClass{
  private __hello: string = 'unset';
  public doSomething(newValue: string | null){
      // works, but I want to remove the class name here
      let converted1: myClass['__hello']; 
      // Private or protected member '__hello' cannot be accessed on a type parameter.(4105)
      let converted2: this['__hello'];
           
      const __this = this;
      let convertedUgly: typeof __this.__hello;  // works but is not nice
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code would get hard to read and understand if there was a support for **calculated types**. I was actually pretty surprised that `myClass['__hello']` have worked. I guess they've added a few working **expression types**, but it doesn't mean you can use any expression.

You should try to **abstract** your code to avoid duplicated fragments, then you won't have to copy and paste code at all.

Here's an example:

```
abstract class Base<T> {
  protected abstract hello: T

  public doSomething(): void {
    let converted: T;
  }
}

class MyClass1 extends Base<string> {
  hello = 'unset'
}

class MyClass2 extends Base<number> {
  hello = 54
}
```

Here I used **generics** to abstract type of `hello` variable, therefore it can be used in `doSomething` function without knowing its type.

I hope it helped